# Exception processing async thread queue java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: android

I am having a problem when I create an array of strings, this only happens in 2.1 android api level 7 or lower and i need to install the application on a device with exactly this configuration, any idea how to solve the problem?
Below the source code, the message that pops up on screen and also logcat's message.

CODE:

```
private String[] fillPedidosName() {
    TipoPedidoDAO tipoDAO = null;
    try {
        tipoDAO = new TipoPedidoDAO();
        pedidosList = tipoDAO.selectAll();
            String[] temp = new String[pedidosList.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < pedidosList.size(); i++) {
            if (pedidosList.get(i) != null) {
                temp[i] = pedidosList.get(i).getDescricao().toString();
            }
        }
        return temp;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        MyLoger.logar(ex);
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (tipoDAO.getDB().isOpen()) {
            tipoDAO.closeConnection();
        }
    }
}
```

THE MESSAGE THAT POPS UP DEBUGING:

Exception processing async thread queue
Exception processing async thread queue
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

lOGCAT'S MESSAGE:

03-03 17:57:57.124: ERROR/jdwp(1267): REQ: UNSUPPORTED (cmd=2/11 dataLen=8 id=0x0012ba)

Comment: remember to mark answers as correct; it encourages people to answer you in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably not using a List that supports get(int).

Try changing your List implementation to ArrayList. When you create your list:

`List myList = new ArrayList()`

This is probably happening inside `tipDAO.selectAll()`.

Comment: thanks Matthew but that was not the problem, I switched to ArrayList and still the same, the problem is when I instantiate a new String (String [] temp = new String [pedidosList.size ()];), very strange...

Comment: it might help to show your .selectAll() code and more information about pedidosList.

Comment: Matthew, with his commentary about the get (i) and .selectAll(), i did some tests, the .selectAll() returnes a ArrayList of Citie's names, to be used in a spinner where the user selects the name to make a purchase, in it i added two strings "Select a City" and "All Cities", i do not know why, when i removed this two Strings everything worked normally ...
If you had not commented I would have wasted too much time to fix this.
THANK YOU Matthew...

Comment: I see this "REQ: UNSUPPORTED" when I am doing remote debugging on an Android device and I try to execute some code from the debugger inline, not sure why it happens... I don't think this answer here is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I got it fixed.
When working with Arrays of your Objects, make sure you have defined a constructor in the object file.

This piece of code was creating the error

```
List<Prediction> predictions = new ArrayList<Prediction>();
```

The fix.
Prediction class file was missing a constructor. After putting in a default constructor, the error is gone for me.

package com.thuptencho.torontotransitbus.models;

```
public class Prediction {
    public String epochTime = "", seconds = "", minutes = "", isDeparture = "", affectedByLayover = "", branch = "",
            dirTag = "", vehicle = "", block = "", tripTag = "";
    //this constructor was missing..after coding this constructor. the error was gone.
    public Prediction(){
        super();
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "epochTime:" + this.epochTime + " seconds:" + this.seconds + " minutes:" + this.minutes
                + " isDeparture:" + this.isDeparture + " affectedByLayover:" + this.affectedByLayover + " branch:"
                + this.branch + " dirTag:" + this.dirTag + " vehicle:" + this.vehicle + " block:" + this.block
                + " triptag:" + this.tripTag;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should a constructor matter?